# Mixing cpu-shares and cpuset-cpus in Docker

Tags: docker, containers, resource-management, cpu-cores

I would like to run two containers with the following resource allocation:

- Container "C1": reserved cpu1, shared cpu2 with 20 cpu-shares
- Container "C2": reserved cpu3, shared cpu2 with 80 cpu-shares

If I run the two containers in this way:

```
docker run -d --name='C1' --cpu-shares=20 --cpuset-cpus="1,2" progrium/stress --cpu 2

docker run -d --name='C2' --cpu-shares=80 --cpuset-cpus="2,3" progrium/stress --cpu 2
```

I got that C1 takes 100% of cpu1 as expected but 50% of cpu2 (instead of 20%), C2 takes 100% of cpu3 as expected and 50% of cpu2 (instead of 80%).

It looks like the --cpu-shares option is ignored.
Is there a way to obtain the behavior I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

[docker run](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/db738dd77f699e93f976441d5fc11ab48a2d6c68/docs/reference/commandline/run.md) mentions that parameter as:

```
--cpu-shares=0                CPU shares (relative weight)
```

And [`contrib/completion/zsh/_docker#L452`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/0439e03a2720987785f98496867c20fd71b9fa44/contrib/completion/zsh/_docker#L452) includes:

```
"($help)--cpu-shares=[CPU shares (relative weight)]:CPU shares:(0 10 100 200 500 800 1000)"
```

So those values are not %-based.

The OP mentions `--cpu-shares=20/80` works with the following [Cpuset constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpuset-constraint):

```
 docker run -ti --cpuset-cpus="0,1" C1 # instead of 1,2
 docker run -ti --cpuset-cpus="3,4" C2 # instead of 2,3
```

(those values are [validated/checked only since docker 1.9.1 with PR 16159](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/16159))

Note: there is also [CPU quota constraint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpu-quota-constraint):

> The `--cpu-quota` flag limits the container’s CPU usage. The default 0 value allows the container to take 100% of a CPU resource (1 CPU).

Comment: I know, I used 20 and 80 to simplify the scenario. Because I have only two containers that need both 100% of cpu (stress) with shares set to 20 and 80 they should run at 20% and 80% respectively on the shared cpu (cpu2). Of course I could have used something like 4 and 16 or 80 and 320.

Comment: No, I mean those values might not be recognized. Try 200 and 800 to see if that works better.

Comment: @GiovanniQuattrocchi and if you reverse the values? (800 and 200 instead of 200 and 800)

Comment: I don't know why but if use cpuset-cpus=0,1 for C1 and cpuset-cpus=1,2 for C2 i got the expected behavior...

Comment: @GiovanniQuattrocchi What version of docker are you using?